# Diagramming default values on unowned fields

Tags: uml

In UML, I diagram class B extending class A. In my actual class implementation, class B's constructor sets default values for protected members of class A. I know how to diagram default values for a class's owned members, but how do I diagram default values for fields which are not owned by the class?

In other words, how do I diagram default values in class B for fields defined in class A?

(note: I'm unable to change the class structure; I'm only diagramming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the way:

[image]

In order to create the picture I used Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect and the ["Features & Properties → Override Attribute Initializers"](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/11/modeling_basics/advancedsettings2.html) context menu operation applied to the inherited `field1` attribute.

So I think that this notation is correct because:

- there is a remarkable tool that supports it
- this notation is also used when showing [slots in object instances](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#slot)
- I'm not aware of any counterargument

Comment: Very interesting; to me it looks like the lack of access modifier, i.e. `- + $` on `field1` in class B implies `field1` in class B was not defined in class B, but by its ancestors. That's what I wanted.

Comment: @dgtc I tried to check this against the [UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) documents  but that's not my favorite reading so I'm relying on other sources. According to uml-diagrams.org it seems that the [visibility modifier is optional](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html) and that's how the EA tool draw it. From the point of view of someone who would read the diagram I don't see a usability problem here. And you can always attach a `note symbol` (with comments) to the diagram at places where is something that needs to be emhasized

Comment: Got it. Visbility modifier is simply optional--it's absence doesn't have any semantic meaning. So, my observation was wrong. My best bet is a note or symbol, so be it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use redefinition of attribute from class A in class B. Redefinition should set default value in class B. Or you can define instance specification (instance of class B) with slots. Fill slot value of specific attribute in instance of class B.

Comment: By redefinition you're suggesting property shadowing? That would require me to change my class definitions, which I can't do, they are fixed. But good tip.